# Classify vector layer by area quantiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, classification, vector-layer

I have a vector layer with aroud 400 features, each having an assigned `value` (here displayed as a label).

[image: QGIS Screenshot]

I want to classify it into 5 groups (10%/20%/40%/20%/10% of the total area) based on the `value` field. Basically taking the features with the lowest `value` and grouping them until their summed area reaches 10% of the total area of all features etc.

Is there a tool for that or do I need to write some Python code for it?